# Best practice for testing smart contract

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, haskell, testnet

Let's say you have your haskell code ready to test as a smart contract on the testnet, what is the best practice to go about testing if your smart contract works as intended? Does the same process work for the mainnet?

Thanks, Myles

Answer (score 1):

This question is too broad. It really depends on the use case you are using the smart contract for. It is like asking what are best practices to test software.

Mainnet and testnet are just different networks, the smart contacts works the same way on both.